# how can I make thumbnail image disappear when the mouse hovers over the title without css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, hover

I have a simple jQuery code to change the thumbnail of a post by hiding one image and showing the other, when I hover over the `div` for the image. The code works for fine when I hover over the `div`s labled in the `.thumbs` class, but I also want to add a feature so that when I hover over the title the same thing happens and the thumbnails change.

The problem is that if I add the `.headline` to the jquery selector I don't get the result I want and the images change when I hover over the thumbnails.

I know why this is happening but don't know how to solve it. Since I only want the image of the post I'm hovering over to change I am using `$(this)`, and since the images are both inside `.thumbs` there is no problem. But the headline isn't inside the `.thumbs` div and therefor when I use `$(this).headline` it's like I'm saying `thumbs.headline` which doesn't exist. How can I not put the headline inside the same `div` and still know which post I'm hovering over?

```
  $('.thumbs').hover(
        function() {
           console.info('in');
    $(this).children('.first').css('display','none'); 
    $(this).children('.second').css('display','block')
                        },
        function() {
        console.info('out');
    $(this).children('.second').css('display','none'); 
    $(this).children('.first').css('display','block');
                    });
```

HTML Code:

```
<h2 class='headline'><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){ ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
<div class='thumbs'>
     <div class='first'><?php the_post_thumbnail()?></div>
     <div class='second'><?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?></div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML code?

Comment: @MarsOne I just edited and added the HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If wrapping them isn't an option, this should work:

```
$('.thumbs').each(function () {

    var thisThumbAndHeadline = $(this).add($(this).prevAll('.headline:first'));

    thisThumbAndHeadline.hover(function () {
        console.info('in');    
        thisThumbAndHeadline.children('.first').hide();
        thisThumbAndHeadline.children('.second').show()
    },

    function () {
        console.info('out');
        thisThumbAndHeadline.children('.first').show();
        thisThumbAndHeadline.children('.second').hide();
    }).trigger('mouseout');

})
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to apply the listener to a wrapper that goes around both the title and the thumbs.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8UP8/

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2 class='headline'> ... </h2>

    <div class='thumbs'>
        <div class='first'> ... /div>
        <div class='second'> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.wrap').hover(
    function() {
        console.info('in');
        $(this).find('.first').css('display','none'); 
        $(this).find('.second').css('display','block')
    },
    function() {
        console.info('out');
        $(this).find('.second').css('display','none'); 
        $(this).find('.first').css('display','block');
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery:

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method hides the selected elements
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method shows the hidden, selected elements